# Shopkeeper selling at a discount

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A shopkeeper sells product at 12% discount on their marked price. They have to pay a 10% tax. If they give a discount of Rs. 6, How much money are they left with after tax?

Correct answer is $237.60$
What I tried so far:-
$12/100*x=36$ where marked price is $x$ and discount is applied on marked price.
Then I applied successive percentage formula.
$a+b+a*b/100= 12+10+120/100=23.2$
$23.2/100*300=69.6$
Money they are left with is= $230.4$

Comment: "...a discount of Rs. 6" : what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

It has a simple solution. Let us assume that $a$ is the discount and $b$ is the tax. Then the money left is calculated from the following formula:

$$f = 300 \frac{100-a}{100} \frac{100-b}{100} = 300 \cdot 0.88 \cdot 0.9 = 237.6$$